# I'm trying to timestamp data from stdin (into a log file) using a Windows Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipe

I'm collecting data from an API using a DOS port of wget to generate data for a log file (which will be analysed at a later date).  The API provides all the information I need except a current time (it provides a time at the start of the stream of data but not again after that).

The API provides, typically 10 lines of data initially and then a line every 20-30 seconds.

I'm trying to timestamp this output and copy it to a log file - I don't mind if the timestamp is on the same line as the rest of the output or the line before.

I first started with this batchfile:

addtimes.bat:

```
@echo off >nul
:start
set /p input="":

echo %time% 
echo %input%

goto:start
```

(called as "wget..... | addtimes.bat > log.log")

However this dropped data comping in - the beginning of many lines of data were lost.

I've looked on here and realised I should use a for loop.

addtimes2.bat:

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('more') do ( 
echo !time! %%a )
)
```

I've tried with and without Enabling Delayed Expansion.

I don't seem to be able to pass information one line at a time with a different timestamp - all my lines get identical timestamps once I close the datastream.

Typical input data is of the form:

```
[1,"219","265",14528,1359031137000,1359031137000]
[1,"6594","358",18188,1359031019000,1359031019000]
[1,"690","94",15920,1359031534000,1359031534000]
[1,"25164","102",2129,1359031457000,1359031457000]


[1,"3488","329",2109,1359030868000,1359030868000]

[1,"37247","6",11506,1359031223000,1359031223000]
```

You may notice there are UTC times in the data but they are not the current time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can get the result you want using pure native batch. The reason why all your times are the same is that the FOR /F loop does not process any lines of input until the entire input stream has been buffered (the command on the left of the pipe has finished). The FOR /F command waits until all the input has been received, and then dumps every line in one mad rush. If the input stream is large enough, you will get slight variations in time, but nothing that comes close to representing when the original command generated each line.

Here is a hybrid JScript/batch script that does what you want. It works fine as a straight JScript file, but then you need to explictly use CSCRIPT. The hybrid approach makes the utility more convenient.

Call it addtimes.bat and use it just as you were before.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"
exit /b 0

************* JScript portion **********/
while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
  var ts = new Date()
  var ms = (ts.getTime() % 1000)
  WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(
    ts.getFullYear() + "-" +
    ((ts.getMonth()<9)?"0":"") + (ts.getMonth()+1) + "-" +
    ((ts.getDate()<10)?"0":"") + ts.getDate() + " " +
    ((ts.getHours()<10)?"0":"") + ts.getHours() + ":" +
    ((ts.getMinutes()<10)?"0":"") + ts.getMinutes() + ":" +
    ((ts.getSeconds()<10)?"0":"") + ts.getSeconds() + "." +
    ((ms<10)?"00":((ms<100)?"0":"")) + ms + " - " +
    WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
  );
}
```

**EDIT**

wmz has a very clever ***and dangerous*** solution. That solution can be simplified - There is no need to muck with Autorun.

***Warning*** *- as wmz said, the solution below can have very bad consequences if any line in the output starts with an executable command or program name! I do not recommend actually using this solution, but I find it very interesting.*

```
(echo @prompt $D $T -$S & YourCommandHere )|cmd 2>nul|findstr /rbc:"../../.... ..:..:..\... - " >log.log
```

The FINDSTR pipe is added to strip out the CMD header info, the initial PROMPT command, and the unwanted blank line that CMD inserts after each "command". The FINDSTR regex may need to change to match the specifics of your chosen prompt and your locale.

Comment: I posted a batch way (more of a hack than anything else)

Comment: Liking your original solution - working just fine - and I understand it. The second one's looking elegant but I wouldn't want to have to explain how it worked! Shouldn't be dangerous for me as all my data should start [x, where x is a 1-digit number. Many thanks.

Comment: Actually am understanding the second one - but might not if I came back to it some time later.

Answer (score 3):

***Please be warned: this may have a lot of side effects (or may not work at all, or make your system unstable etc.) and is not tested. It's more of exercise in batch than anything else***

**EDIT:** See debenham's answer for refined way of using this idea.

1. set prompt to time (`prompt $T`) or date time if you prefer (`prompt $D $T`). You will have to do it in `Autorun` key in Registry (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\Microsoft\Command Processor`) so it's default. If there is no Autorun key, create it (it contains commands executed when cmd prompt is opened)
2. Start cmd prompt, then pipe output of your command to another `cmd.exe`, and redirect output of that to file:
   `more | cmd 2>nul >timestamped.log` (you'd use your command where I used `more`). With `more`, entering:

> this is a message
>   which was timestamped ^Z

produces following lines in timestamped.log (after two lines with cmd processor version info):

> 23:19:57,17_this is a message
>   23:19:59,95_which was timestamped

This works because cmd will try to execute your log entry. This fails (and error message is supressed/sent to nul), but at the same time echoes it together with prompt (time/date).

**You must be very careful** if your log messages are not quoted (*or more generally, if you're not sure of their format, or they are not created under your direct control*) - if your line happens to start with a word which is a valid command - it will be executed!

Comment: Oooh, +1 for being very clever. -1 to anyone that actually uses this hack in production :-)

Comment: I added a variant of your solution to my answer. No need to mess with Autorun.

Comment: @dbenham Agreed, I actually first started with 'I would never use this in production' but then restated as too negative :-). Your version is nice, passing prompt as one of commands seems obvious in hindsight (as it always is :-))